# How to define constant incremental counter

Tags: java, interface

If you have list of columns for some table and you define the meta data for those columns in a interface:

```
interface tableCol{
  String column1 = "col1";
  String column2 = "col2";
  int col1_pos = 1;
  int col2_pos = 2;
}
```

Value of Col1_pos is used for display purpose in UI.

We have around 100 columns && depending on user requirements, the position keep changing.

For any column addition/removal, I have to update the hardcoded counters .

Is there a better way to do this by using some Integer or supplier, which increments value?

I am aware that Javc/JVM does some reordering of instructions. So, I am looking for a better approach so that i dont need to hardcode these counter values.

Comment: Huh? Why do you care about runtime optimizations by the jit?

Comment: use an `enum` for the colums and use the `ordinal()` method for a columns index in the column list.

Comment: misusing an interface to define constants is an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0):

The common thing to do is to put these values into an interable list. So instead of defining individual fields such as `column1`, `column2` etc to a `List`. But since there's more information attached per column (name and "pos"), you could also create a column-class that contains both fields and store those in a collection.

But since you only want to store name and an index, you can use java's `enum` and use the ordinal method as the index like this:

```
enum Columns {
  COL1 ("col1"),    //ordinal() = 0
  COL2 ("col2"), ;  //ordinal() = 1

  String name;
  public Columns(String name){
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```